# Repeating query parameters in Rest-Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a `Map<String, Object>` of parameters. Some of these parameters have lists and rest assured will set the parameter value as a comma separated list:

`http://url.com/rest?field1=value&fieldlist=1,2,3`

I am using jersey and for some reason it doesn't accept these CSV lists. It accepts parameter lists with repeating values:

`http://url.com/rest?field1=value&fieldlist=1&fieldlist=2&fieldlist=3`

Is there a way I can configure rest-assured to write lists in this way?

This is marked as a duplicate and it can no longer be answered, but I found the answer to the question.

**Answer:**

I was using rest-assured version 1.8.2 but I needed to update to 1.9.0. This issue is directly reported here: https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/issues/detail?id=169&can=1&q=query%20parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In REST Assured you just do like this:

```
given().queryParam("fieldlist", "1", "2", "3"). ..
```

You don't need to construct the URL manually. Version `1.9.0` is also really old. You should update to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the values for the fields in the path manually. I was also on version 1.8.2 which still did not support repeating query parameters because of [an issue with rest-assured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/issues/detail?id=169&can=1&q=query%20parameters). Updating to 1.9.0 allowed me to repeat the query parameters manually in the path.